# Button Movement Control in AS3 Error

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, adobe

In actionscript 3.0, I am creating an iOS app with Adobe Air. For the main player's movement, I am using buttons. Whenever I run the code, I get an error. The code is as follows.

```
stop()
up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_up);

function fl_up() {
        player.x += 5;
}
```

If anyone could tell me what is wrong with this code it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you post a question about an error you're receiving, it's most helpful when you share the error code/text.  Turn on debugging, and you'll know exactly why & where your code is breaking.  That said, you forgot to hold an argument in your event listener; I suspect that's the culprit.

```
stop() // <- If this is the only frame on your document, you really don't need this.

up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_up);

function fl_up(e:MouseEvent):void {
        player.x += 5;
}
```